# Orientation change messes up my WebView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview

All I want is that text to go back to where it was, because there is a huge gap, any idea how to do it?

At first

[image: In the beginning]

---

And then

[image: In the end...]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this line in your Manifest in relevant activity tag

```
android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|screenLayout"
```

Comment: I already have that it does't solves my problem... any other opinion?

Comment: It should work!make sure you add this in right activity!
it's the easy way and best way,by the way,you can do it manually on savedInstanceState method.search and find about it.
but still say the easy and best way is use above solution ,that prevents activty restart on orientation change

Comment: I only have 1 activity... `<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|keyboardHidden|keyboard">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>`

Comment: Here it is... `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>`

Comment: ok,I test it in both my phone and my tablet,all things work fine,
in my phone,I scroll down and then rotate to land,again rotate it to be port,
About a second problem that happened for you came,and fixed quickly  automatically!
this is what I do:
        WebView wb= (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        //wb.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        wb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        wb.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

try your code on other devices.

Comment: and when i set webView match_parent in both width and height ,I did not see that problem

Comment: your Welcome friend,
if the problem fixed on other device, accept my answer for others have same issue